# Read Azure blob storage in Databricks using key vault

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

Below is my code to read a container in my Azure Storage account from a notebook in Databricks. I am generating SAS key at container for authenticating my storage account. However now My notebook now will run as a part of JOB that is daily and SAS token comes with an expiry date.I dont want to generate a SAS token for an Year or so. I am wondering how can I fix this maybe using storage account primary key is an option here. Can someone direct me as what are the ways we can do it and if there is a code snippet where we fetch key from Key vault and use it to read the data as I do in below code:

```
    spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.mycontainer.storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net","<mysastoken>")
    dbutils.fs.ls("wasbs://myconatiner@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/")
   file_path ="wasbs://myconatiner@storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/topics/logs"
   (spark.readStream
    .format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "json")  
    .schema(schema)
    .load(file_path)
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .toTable(table_name))
```

Comment: do you have a service principal that has access to that blob storage? Primary key is much worse solution compared to other methods

Comment: I dont , but any guide on how can i do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#direct-access-using-abfs-uri-for-blob-storage-or-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2

Answer (score 0):

To read files from blob storage in azure data bricks using azure key vault you need to follow below procedure:

Add `Storage blob data contributor` role to yourself. Create Azure key vault and create secret with access key of blob storage account as secret value.

[image]

[image]

Create azure Databricks workspace, launch, create secret scope by using `https://<databricksinstance>#secrets/createScope` URL  and go to key vault properties tab copy `Vault URI` ,`Resource ID`

[image]

Paste them at creation of secret scope

[image]

Mount the storage account using below code:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "wasbs://<ContainerName>@<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net",
mount_point = "/mnt/files",
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storageaccountName>.blob.core.windows.net":dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<ScretscopeName>", key = "<secretName>")})
```

[image]

Read file from mount path using below code:

```
df = spark.read.text("/mnt/files/employees.csv")
df.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did the above steps and I get error as 
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The String is not a valid Base64-encoded string. in dbutils.fs.mount() step.

Comment: There is no space in my generated screts, I checked twice

Comment: Now I tried with container key instead of SAS key and it moved to next stage. in next stage I get error as Container in account not found and we cant create it using anonymous credentials

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/integrate-databricks-blob-storage) for reference.

Comment: and it seems you need to give the folder name till where you file resides so if I have a folder like year inside files folder I need to give mount= mnt/files/year in order to read the file inside year folder. Problem is I have list of files to be read. how can i do that?

Comment: Try this format `/mnt/files/*/*.csv`